# Set the laravel site name with a value from the DB

Tags: php, laravel-8

I'm working on company site and I have a question... I have **general settings** in SQL, how to get **site_name** from Database and put it into **.env** file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overwriting directly the .env file, you can force the config setting in your `AppServiceProvider`, in the `boot` function add these lines:

```php
$appName = "perform query to obtain the appName"; // Perform your actual query
\Config::set('app.name', $appName);
```

You can avoid an additional query to the database at each request by addind a cache layer:

```php
$appName = Cache::get('appName', ''); 

if (empty($appName)) {
  $appName = "your query";
  Cache::put('appName', $appName, 10 /* minutes */); 
}

\Config::set('app.name', $appName);
```